# add bitmap to existing TImage picture (vcl)

Tags: c++builder, vcl, timage

I'm building a VCL Forms Application in RAD Studio using C++.  On the Form, I have a `TImage` object named `Image2`.  I can add a picture to it like this:

```
Image2->Canvas->Draw(0, 0, Image1->Picture->Graphic);
```

Now, I want to add another picture on top of it (not replacing the present picture, but adding to it).  How do I do this?

Also, is there a way to do this and be able to use the mouse to move around and add the second picture wherever I want it?

The main thing - I want to add the new picture to the existing, not simply replace it.

Comment: You are already doing what you are asking for - drawing a new graphic on top of an existing graphic - so what are you really having trouble with? Just handling the mouse? Use the `TImage::OnMouse...` events, using `OnMouse(Down|Up)` to know when to draw, and using `OnMouseMove` to call `TMouse::CursorPos` and `TImage::ScreenToClient()` to determine where to draw. Though, you might consider using a `TPaintBox` instead of a `TImage`, and then draw your graphics in its `OnPaint` event. Or simply place multiple `TImage` objects on a `TScrollBox` or other container and then move them around

Comment: by adding it you mean combine both images like alpha blending or xoring or adding?  or just draw some image over another image which have not 100% overlap/coverage because of different resolution or position ? Where is the problem? Hope You know `Draw` will not resize your image if that is what you want you can try `Image2->Assign (Image1);`  or use `SetSize` or `SetBounds` or `Width,Height` or whichever properties and methods your Image has.